# How to position a text right below an image(like a card)

Tags: html, css, position, margin

I'm new to programming and CSS. I'm not really that familiar with CSS and I'm currently trying to learn it. I'm trying to put an image and some text right below it. I put a background color to the text and changed the opacity a bit to make it look nicer. The way I did it was first position the image where I wanted it to be, and then position the text right below it. But this takes up a LOT of time as I was using margins. I kept having to change it to get it perfectly below it. There has to be a better way, right? Could someone please tell me if there is a better way and if so, how to position the text below the image for my code?

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="RPSprev">
    <img src="/assets/RPSprev.png" class="projectPreviews">
    <p id="RPSprev-header">Rock Paper Scissors</p><br>
    <pre>
    <p id="RPSprev-para">
        Rock paper scissors is a hand game usually played between two people, in which
        each player simultaneously forms one of three shapes with an outstretched hand. 
        These shapes are 'rock', 'paper', and 'scissors'
    </p>
    <pre>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.projectPreviews {
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 24%;
    border-top-left-radius: 13px;
    border-top-right-radius: 13px;
}

#RPSprev-header {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 50px;
    top: 820px;
    left: 23.75%;
    height: 30%;
    width: 53.25%;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.6);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
}

#RPSprev-para {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -750;
    left: 350;
}
```

Here is what I've made using margin. However, it took a lot of time.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you position `.projectPreviews` (the image) absolute. This means that all content that follows will move under it. Maybe you did this to move the image to the center of the screen?
It looks like you first need to learn some more about HTML and CSS.

Anyway, this might help:

```html
<div id="RPSprev">
    <img src="/assets/RPSprev.png">
    <div id="RPSprevContent">
        <h2>Rock Paper Scissors</h2>
        <p><pre> Rock paper scissors is a hand game usually played between two people, in which
        each player simultaneously forms one of three shapes with an outstretched hand. 
        These shapes are 'rock', 'paper', and 'scissors'</pre></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#RPSprev {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -400px;
  top: 40px;
}
#RPSprev img {
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 13px 13px 0 0;
}
#RPSprevContent {
  background: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.6);
  border-radius: 0 0 13px 13px;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `<br>` or `flex-direction: column` on `#RPSprev` so everything aligns neatly, then just center the text with `text-align: center`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler demo of the problem you asked. The solution i provided is using flex box. Make sure the p tag also has a `margin:0` to remove the space between the image and the text.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.wrapper img {
  width: 50%
}
.wrapper p {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1600/1*8du96SQUQ0NlWmWvVu20Zw.png" alt="game image">
  <p> Some text here and description... </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To position some text below an image like a caption, you can just use the `<picture>` element in HTML. Here's an example:

```html
 <picture style="border:1px solid black">
  <img src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/94013/original/image-20150907-22253-rnp0iv.jpg?auto=format&q=45&w=1356&h=668&fit=scale" height="200px" width="200px"><br>
  <caption>This is a caption</caption>
</picture> 

<br><br>
<span>This is some test outside of the picture element</span>
```

I have added border to the picture element just to show its dimensions and boundaries.